# Single point is buggy in flot.js chart

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, flot

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to implement a flot chart correctly. It's a line chart with dates on the X axis and decimal values on the Y axis.

The chart displays fine, but there's a single point which is, essentially, at the correct place on the graph, but then spans all the way through it.

See screenshot for reference: [image]

I have checked that the date value of the point is correct (it's 30/9/2015 (EU date format) and the next is 1/10/2015 (EU date format)) The decimal number is also correctly placed, it seems.

The JSON that I'm using is this: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c2b1ad443d9de74a607)

The JSON data comres from an ASP.NET webserver.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the problem? What does "spans all the way through it" mean?

Comment: In my screenshot, there's only two lines: the blue and the yellow. The first yellow marking/dot is creating a line all the way through the graph it seems, which it should not.

Comment: Oh OK, so it's that yellow line that goes from one side to the other. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's the one :-)

Comment: There's a 2015 date at the very end of the array. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp of the last record in your gist is the smallest timestamp, which means it should be the first record to plot properly. Flot plots data in the order that data is fed to it -- you should sort it before you feed it to Flot for plotting.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed :-) an `.OrderBy()` on the server made it work. Thanks!